# VBA BUSCARV toma datos de hoja anterior automatico

Tags: excel, vba

soy nuevo en VBA y necesito ayuda con este codigo:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'02-01-2024'!R2C3:R74C4,2,0)"
```

El BUSCARV regresa a un hoja que es "02-01-2024" a tomar datos, pero me gustaría saber hay alguna forma de que tome siempre la hoja anterior a la actual, por ejemplo,

`=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'Hoja anterior a la actual'!R2C3:R74C4,2,0)`

Porque quizás estaré en "04-01-2024" y necesito los datos de la "03-01-2024", pero esa formula me tomara las de "02-01-2024". Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: [Propiedad Worksheet.Index (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.index) puede devolverte el índice de la hoja actual. Restas al índice 1 y entonces estarás usando la hoja anterior

Comment: Muchas gracias Esei, me trae el numero de sheet que es, ahora me falta que en ves de darme el numero, me de el nombre del sheet y estariamos listo creo, muchas gracias!!! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te pongo un sencillo ejemplo de cómo conseguir el nombre de la hoja anterior a la activa.

```
Sub test()
Dim idx As Integer
Dim HojaAnterior As String

idx = ActiveSheet.Index
HojaAnterior = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(idx - 1).Name

MsgBox HojaAnterior

End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Maestro muchas graciaas‍♂️